# ignite : Filtering of data before putting it to cache

Tags: ignite

I am planning to use IgniteDataStreamer along with StreamVisitor API to filter some type of data before putting it to cache.

Are there any other ways or API for filtering of Streaming data before putting it to ignite cache.

I'm aware of the fact that Once the data is put into the cache then normal SQL way of filtering is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamVisitor` allows you to implement a custom filtering logic directly on remote nodes where the data goes.

Another option is to implement a custom `CacheStore`
[CacheStore.loadCache](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading#section-ignitecacheloadcache)

And, of course, if it's possible, you could filter the data before feeding it into a data streamer.

Comment: What about CacheInterceptor<K,V> during the cache configuration. Does this help me filtering of data before feeding it into streamer

Comment: `CacheInterceptor` is more like `StreamVisitor` and is not directly related to `Streamer`s. `CacheInterceptor`s are executed on the nodes where entries are about to be put (there are additional callbacks too).
I would suggest you stick with either `Streamer`+`StreamVisitor` or `CacheStore`

Comment: From what I understand CacheStore is used for bulk loading of data to cache like in startup. How can CacheStore be used for streaming data along with filtering?

Comment: If you need populating data not only at the startup time but also in runtime, then the preferred solution is `IgniteDataStreamer`+`StreamVisitor`.

Comment: if I use StreamVisitor, the the logic of filtering should be written in the overriden method apply(). But I'm interested in an API that would take the filtering expression as an argument and start filtering the data.

Comment: Then `StreamVisitor#from` is worth taking a look on it.
Setting a filter could be as easy as follows
`IgniteDataStreamer<Object, Object> dataStreamer = igniteClient.dataStreamer("cacheName");
dataStreamer.receiver(StreamVisitor.from((cache, entry) -> {
    // your filtering logic goes here
}));`

Comment: Thank you @ alexfedotov for your answer. The requirement got tweaked a bit, hence I'm using ignite tables rather than operating directly on cache.